# How to simulate Accept header in a test within a Laravel 5 package?

Tags: php, testing, laravel-5, phpunit, package

I'm currently building a Laravel package that injects a new method in `Illuminate\Http\Request` via [Macros](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.html). The method I'm injecting has been completed and is expected to work nicely, but I also want to test it before releasing it.

My test requires me to change the request's `Accept` header, in order for me to see if the test is passing or no. So I have done the following to simulate the request:

```
// package/tests/TestCase.php

namespace Vendor\Package;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase as Orchestra;

abstract class TestCase extends Orchestra
{
    /**
     * Holds the request
     * @var Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Setup the test
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->request = Request::capture();

        $this->request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/x-yaml');
    }
}
```

Then in my test I use the method I'm injecting into `Request` with `$this->request->wantsYaml()` and it's always returning false since the `Accept` header is not getting set to `application/x-yaml`.

```
class RequestTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_should_return_a_bool_if_page_wants_yaml_or_not()
    {
        dump($this->request->wantsYaml()); // Return false

        $this->assertTrue($this->request->wantsYaml()); // It fails!
    }
}
```

How do I go on simulating the headers in a test in Laravel package development?

---

**EDIT**

This is my `YamlRequest` class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class YamlRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Acceptable content type for YAML.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $contentTypeData = ['/x-yaml', '+x-yaml'];

    /**
     * Determine if the current request is asking for YAML in return.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function wantsYaml()
    {
        $acceptable = $this->getAcceptableContentTypes();

        // If I dd($acceptable), it comes out as empty during tests!

        return isset($acceptable[0]) && Str::contains($acceptable[0], $this->contentTypeData);
    }
}
```

So I literally have to simulate the Accept in order to see if my `wantsYaml` method is working as expected.

Comment: Please include your class or the part of class where you want to do it and how you pass/create Request object in this class

Comment: Added the `use` statement.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Which class exactly do you mean? I only want  to simulate the Content-Type header for my tests. My code works as it should (I believe), but I need this simulation in my tests in order to prove it.

Comment: You should include at least  `myMethod` - how it's using this header for example and how it's returning the value

Comment: Ill update the question altogether with concrete code.

Comment: What does `Accept` header contain while you do a test?

Comment: @revo if I `dd($this->request)` then the header is set as it should, but when I go into the method itself and `dd($acceptable)` then it's empty!

Comment: Something is odd! If I pass `wantsYaml` method as Macro to `Request` it's working for me: https://gist.github.com/maxwilms/7342c9ea5c2052505212e2d15cfc108b
I'm wondering how are you passing the `YamlRequest` class to `Request`? Please include your Service Provider!

Answer (score 1):

A partially mocked object would allow you to test your `Illuminate\Http\Request::macro` without also testing ancillary methods within Laravel's `Illuminate\Http\Request` object. In other words, all you really need to know is that your macro works. You don't need to test that a `Request` can be constructed and that its headers can be set.

In the following tests, I'll setup a "partially" mocked version of your `YamlRequest` object using Mockery.

> Partial mocks are useful when we only need to mock several methods of an object leaving the remainder free to respond to calls normally (i.e. as implemented).

*See the [Mockery Documentation, Creating Partial Mocks](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html).*

The partial mock will allow us to mock the methods from Laravel's `Request` object while leaving your macro free to run as it would in a production environment.

```php
use YamlRequest;
use \Mockery;

class RequestTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->request = Mockery::mock(YamlRequest::class)->makePartial();
    }

    public function test_that_wants_yaml_returns_true_given_x-yaml_accept_header()
    {
        /**
         *  This line allows you to control the return value of
         *  Illuminate\Http\Request::getAcceptableContentTypes while your macro
         *  is running.
         */
        $this->request->allows(
            [
                'getAcceptableContentTypes' => ['application/x-yaml', 'text/html']
            ]
        );

        $this->assertTrue($this->request->wantsYaml());
    }

    public function test_that_wants_yaml_returns_false_given_json_accept_header()
    {
        $this->request->allows(
            [
                'getAcceptableContentTypes' => ['application/json', 'text/html']
            ]
        );

        $this->assertFalse($this->request->wantsYaml());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the app with a unit test, there is a prebuilt laravel **`assertHeader()`** and **`assertHeaderMissing()`** functions that might help you. Refer to the [Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests#assert-header) Here. Here is the code snippet taken from Docs,

```php
$response->assertHeader($headerName, $value = null);
$response->assertHeaderMissing($headerName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, to be honest I don't know how you use this `YamlRequest` in your code but I think there are 2 problems here:

1) In your test you create `Illuminate\Http\Request` object and not `YamlRequest` object - is it correct? For me it seems not but maybe it should be like this

2) Second thing is the code of the method. Looking at your method implementation you set invalid header because `getAcceptableContentTypes()` method gets `Accept` header and not `Content-Type`

If I change code of test to something like this:

```
$request = new \App\Http\Requests\YamlRequest();
$request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/x-yaml');
$this->assertTrue($request->wantsYaml());
```

it passes. But I had to use `Accept` header and not `Content-Type`. I think that's the error.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that part as I should have. I use a macro (see Macroable trait in Laravel) and I inject the YamlRequest via the Service Provider of the package, therefore I have the `wantsYaml()` method available in the `Request` class.

In my TestCase class, I tried switching the header to `Accept` in the `setUp` method, but it didn't work. I'll update my code above.

Comment: Also please consider that all of this is happening inside a single laravel package without the real "application" part!